# GCE Load Balancer https and http routes

Tags: https, google-cloud-platform

I have a load balancer that connected to a few backend instances in my cloud. Everything works great but the problem is that I need to put a specific sub domain route so the HTTPS protocol will work too.

Let's say I have xyz.com on PORT 80 and www.xyx.com on 443 - I want both of them to work the same.

I just created two incoming traffic IPs, the first one for the regular HTTP protocol and second for the HTTPs protocol. Each of them doing the job great but it's not automatically routing me to the right protocol when I'm accessing to the domain.

Any ideas or sources that can help me?

Comment: Take a look at Cross-Region Load Balancing example at this link. You can configure both HTTP and HTTPS on the same IP/domain name: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example

Comment: @Kamran is there any chance that I can integrate nodes of GKE and not a regular instances?

Comment: Yes, you can, please visit this article: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Comment: @Kamran thanks a lot!